# Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user after redirecting to HTTPS and Non-WWW via HTACCESS

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, 301-redirect, canonical-url, google-selected-canonical

I have redirected the **www** version and **http** version to **non-www** and **https** so the URL will be like https://website.com using the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also I have written canonical tag like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/" />
```

(I don't know if I should do this or no.)

In google Search Console it's displaying "Duplicate, Google choose Different canonical than user" and not indexing my pages.

I tried updating the canonical URL and by removing it too. but still the problem is not solved. What should I do and what is the best way to do it? can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I just found google is indexing http:// www.website.com URL and not https:// website.com it's displaying in Google-selected canonical

Comment: Your redirect *should* point to the same URL as the canonical link (but that should be www.website.com rather than website.com)